# Saving purchased details for the app

Tags: android, apk

I am hosting a paid app. I have a query. How a person purchasing the app is recorded so as to when they need to re-download (say after wiping phone or refreshing the phone software) is the previous purchase recognised. Is there a registration or something that I would need to keep (or is it recommended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is downloadable from the Google play store then there is nothing you need to do. The play store will automatically work out when the user visits your apps page whether they need to purchase, whether they have purchased, or whether they purchased and then refunded.

The only thing you might want to do is to add some code at the start of your app launching that automatically checks google servers and ensures that the purchase has been made, otherwise you can block the app. Although this isn't fool proof but it highly reduces the changes of your app being pirated.